# why doesnt everyone use frameworks

Tags: frameworks

well lot of forums and even this site is full of questions where people don't use any framework(whetever language they use) and they are stuck on code for common tasks like logins,database accesses,etc while frameworks provide code that works correctly for these routine tasks. Then why do people still go without frameworks? i want to know this because i am trying to build something of substantial scale so i was deciding if i really need a framework or a homegrown solution would be better? a homegrown solution can be a great learning experience but is there something more to it?

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase your question somehow. In the current form it's very subjective. You can make clearer why do you wan't to know this?

Comment: Counter-question: Why doesn't everyone use one programming language? (the answer, I suspect, will be very similar)

Answer (score 5):

Some reasons:

- Some tasks are so small that it's easier to do them without a framework, which:

  - would have to be bundled;
  - would take up an order of magnitude more space than the app itself;
  - would impose a lot of requirements both for the app and the hosting platform;
  - would provide unnecessary overhead because of a lot of features which are unused in the particular app;
- Wanting to find out about how things work;
- Homework assignments;
- Not being able to use the framework for some reason (constrained space, not enough permissions, etc.)
- Not knowing about these frameworks;
- Reducing dependencies on external libraries;
- Legacy reasons (the app is old, it was started before any serious frameworks were out);

Comment: Vilx-: so u mean that if i am developing a large application i should definitely use a framework? Is learning a framework worth the effort(I am talking about Zend and CodeIgniter) and are there any downsides to it?

Comment: @lovesh - in the general case you would probably benefit from that. However each case is special and you should consider carefully. Better consult with someone who knows the particular framework to find out whether it would be a good fit for your task.

Comment: @lovesh - note that if the app is large you will end up using **some** kind of framework anyway. The choice is just between using an existing one or rolling out your own. An existing framework will be more bug-free and mature, while your own will be tailored specifically to your requirements. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

People go without framework for several different reasons, in my opinion the choice of developing in-house functionality is not always a bad choice.

- Frameworks often don't implement all functionalities required but often add extra functionalities that will never be used making the code base unecessary "bloated".
- Implementing a framework often requires a steep learning curve and often it is easier to implement certain functionality in house.
- However often a framework can be the best choice but developers jump into coding without doing enough research beforehand.